# Can the Protoss Mothership Mass Recall Allies' units?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

If so, there's a wicked opportunity in 4v4 to mothership rush to an enemies base and recall 400 units into his base!!!

Comment: To address the actual opportunity: Also consider that you could recall 800 units in his base, or more limited depending on the amount of population the units take. Also, you are most likely unable to get the Mother-ship all the way to his base without your opponent interfering with that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It can not.](http://sc2pod.com/wiki/Mass_Recall) Here's an excerpt:

> Teleports all units owned by the player (but not units of teammates)
>   in the target area to the Mothership.

Comment: this would be nice, but it doesn't work. try it.

Comment: Does that really work? Does one need to share control to recall allied forces?

Comment: :( I really wanna do this... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJIfohBaGrk

Comment: Soooo..... What happens if you were to neural parasite an allies mothership?

Comment: e-rock- you should be able to recall any protoss units you own as zerg (via neuraling a probe).   Also, beautiful things: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9mK2Y8aOIo

Answer (score 1):

The mothership cannot recall your partner's units, only your own.